# getting the value of found_records from stored procedure with prepared statement

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here is the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN

SET @sql = concat(@sql ,'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ');
SET @sql = concat(@sql ,';');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

SELECT found_rows();
END
```

The php that calls the stored procedure.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($databaseHostname1, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword);
if(!$mysqli) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysqli_select_db($mysqli, '$db');
if(!$mysqli) die('Could not connect to DB: ' . mysql_error()); 

if ($keywordParam != ''){
$mysqli->query("SET @p_keywordParam = " . "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($keywordParam) . "'");
}else{
$mysqli->query("SET @p_keywordParam = NULL");
}

$mysqli->query("SET @p_pageOffset = $pageOffset");

$result = $mysqli->query("CALL getInventory2(@p_keywordParam,@p_pageOffset)");
if(!$result) die("CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
```

I then output the data

```
NUMBER OF RESULTS: <? echo <<<<<<< FOUND ROWS HERE >>>>>>>>>   ?>
PAGE 1 of ?


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
<? echo $row['FIRST_NAME']; ?>
<? echo $row['LAST NAME']; ?>
```

What I need is the found_rows count from the stored procedure prior to the while loop so that I can setup pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Just after running your query, run this one:

> SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS int_count

Comment: In the Stored procedure or as another call from php?, there is already a SELECT found_rows in the SP.

Comment: Just run your first query without the found rows, and execute it. Once done, run a second query with just the found rows. It is how I am doing it with mysql, so I am guessing it shouldnt be too different in mysqli !!

Comment: I am able to achieve the correct results when running everything on the PHP page, it's when the call is to a STORED PROCEDURE. Are you calling a SP, or calling the queries directly on the php page.

Comment: On the php level, as I am not really familiar with SP I am afraid. Are you running it on 2 different queries on the SP ?

Comment: Yeah on the php level I can do what I want, i just need to have this run from a SP.

Comment: From what I understand (again I'm not a SP expert), it looks like on the line {$result = $mysqli->query("CALL getInventory2(@p_keywordParam,@p_pageOffset)");}, you will return only one result into $result. So the result of your second query will be lost anyway. Can't you call a second SP ? Or return the first one as an array of ($results, $intCountRows) ??